# Can't understand a paragraph in "CSS The Definitive Guide 3rd edition"

Tags: css

In "CSS The Definitive Guide 3rd edition", Page 166, there is a paragraph described a behavior 
about horizontal margins:

> Note that since horizontal margins do not collapse, the padding, borders, and margins of a parent element can affect its children. The effect is indirect in that the margins (and so on) of an element can induce an offset for child elements.

I also can't understand the example provided by the book for this behavior:

http://jsfiddle.net/PjTA3/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p>A paragraph</p>
    <p>Another paragraph</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {padding: 30px; background: silver;}
p {margin: 20px; padding: 20px; background: white;}
```

Can any one explain this to me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://books.google.co.in/books?id=rdtCRLXAL78C&lpg=PP1&dq=CSS%20The%20Definitive%20Guide%203rd%20edition&pg=PA166#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: I don't understand what they mean either .. I guess all that gray space at the top and bottom?  But what would you expect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[I created a fiddle to provide a live example of the code under discussion](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/sVnKM/). If you're using Chrome or a similar modern browser, you can right-click the paragraphs in the example and select 'Inspect element' to see how the paddings and margins interact.

The paragraph in question is horribly written, I agree. It starts off stating that *"horizontal margins do not collapse"*, and then presents an example in which there are no adjacent horizontal margins to demonstrate the assertion. The example does feature adjacent *vertical* margins though (the first paragraph's bottom margin, and the second paragraph's top margin), and we can see that these *do* collapse (they occupy the same space: inspect one element and then the other to see this).

However, this has nothing to do with the non-stacking offsets demonstrated in the example, which is that the paragraphs' *non-adjacent* margins offset them from the edge of the *padding* of the containing div — hence why the first paragraph's top, left, and right edges are `50px` from the outer edge of the div (`20px` margin from the `<p>` + `30px` padding from the `<div>`) .

I think an accurate caption for the example would better be written as

> As a rule, margins, padding and borders do not collapse — except for the vertical margins of block level elements (with exceptions defined in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins)). Inline elements' positioning is not affected by vertical dimensions.

#### EDIT:

Corrected slight inaccuracy in alternative caption: the exception to which, and the original paragraph's assertion that *"horizontal margins do not collapse"* is still unproven: [I created a similar fiddle here to demonstrate this](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/YgBz9/).

In this second example, we've substituted inline `<span>` elements for our `<p>`s, which allows us to see elements naturally flowing on from each other horizontally: unlike the first example — where the second paragraph's top margin collapsed into the first paragraph's bottom margin — the second paragraph's left margin does not collapse into the first one's right margin, instead starting immediately afterwards — putting them `40px` apart.

Incidentally, this also demonstrates that *inline* elements' vertical padding, borders and margins *do* collapse: the top and bottom padding and margin of these spans does not affect their offset from their container.

Comment: Shame I can upvote only once; there are at least three points to your answer I want to upvote.

Comment: Not just is that paragraph confusingly written. It is also placed in a chapter about the `auto` value of margins... at least in the [2nd edition](http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=31159&BookID=23890&PageIndex=57&Language=3#css2-CHP-7-SECT-2.1.3)

Comment: @hsan I agree, the whole thing is a confused mess — forever deviating from the purported focus (having said that, [many people disagree strongly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199486/what-is-the-best-book-on-css)). I feel bad saying it, but the leading lights of the CSS community have always been incredibly bad at expressing themselves clearly. I suppose that's because CSS and human semantics are so often mutually exclusive!

Comment: Glad to know why i can't understand this paragraph because its horribly written; Not because my poor english. Thanks @barney.

Comment: No probs @merlin. To give credit to the book's author (despite the book), he is actually one of the most knowledgeable people in the world about CSS2, and administrates the excellent [CSS-discuss mailing list](http://www.css-discuss.org/), which is a fantastic resource for discussing the intricacies of CSS in formats not so suited to StackOveflow's Q&A style.

Comment: Just realised I left out the demonstration of the horrible paragraph's first assertion, and also made a technical inaccuracy in my revised caption — please see edited post.

Comment: Could you clarify your alternative caption and the edit? As far as I'm aware, horizontal margins do not collapse, ever, and there are no exceptions. From what I make of the question, the only issue seems to be that the example does not demonstrate horizontal margins not collapsing, but the alternative caption you proposed seems to suggest otherwise. Is that the inaccuracy you're referring to in your edit? If so, what about the assertion remaining unproven?

Comment: @BoltClock I see what you're saying — the sentence is still misleading. The point of the edit was to give some demonstration of horizontal measures not collapsing, because it's one of the key assertion of the original statement. Do you think this caption works better: _« As a rule, margins, padding and borders do not collapse — except for the vertical margins of block level elements. Inline elements' positioning is not affected by vertical dimensions. »_ ?

Comment: @Barney: Yeah, that looks much better. There are certain exceptions to vertical margin collapse which are described in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins).